# AWS ELB cloudformation by conditonsfor both HTTPS & HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, elastic-load-balancer

As i am trying to create ELB with the condition where in IsSSL = HTTPS/HTTP
  HttpS=443, HttP=80.

The above values are passed from an yaml file as variables.

If the condition is true it should select respective loadbalancer port using the Fn::If conditons. But i am getting the error when building the stack and the subnets section below works fine. Any Help on this?

Error: Value of property loadbalancerport must be of type String

```
  Conditions:
    IsSSl:
      'Fn::Equals':
        - $(IsSSL)
        - HTTPS

  RsbatchELB:
      DependsOn: RsbatchELBSecurityGroup
      Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
      Properties:
        Listeners:
          - LoadBalancerPort:
              - 'Fn::If':
                  - IsSSL
                  - $(HttpS)
                  - $(HttP)
        Subnets:
          - 'Fn::If':
              - IsPublicELB
              - $(publicSubnet-a)
              - $(private-subnet-a)
          - 'Fn::If':
              - IsPublicELB
              - $(publicSubnet-b)
              - $(private-subnet-b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `LoadBalancerPort` a list with that stray `-`. Try this instead:

```
Listeners:
  - LoadBalancerPort:
      'Fn::If':
         - IsSSL
         - $(HttpS)
         - $(HttP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to use intrinsic function syntax that is not consistent with the [AWS Condition Functions documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if)

There it states this syntax:

> Syntax for the full function name:

```
Fn::If: [condition_name, value_if_true, value_if_false]
```

> Syntax for the short form:

```
!If [condition_name, value_if_true, value_if_false]
```

Try:

```
- LoadBalancerPort:
  - !If [IsSSL, !Ref HttpS, !Ref HttP]
```